# Merge LEFT JOIN rows then search for phrases

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have a problem with my mysql query. I have two tables:

"data" table:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | one |
| 2 | two |

and "fields" table:

| id | data_id | type | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | foostring |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | barstring |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | string |
| 4 | 2 | 1 | foobarstring |
| 5 | 2 | 2 | string |
| 6 | 2 | 3 | string |

I want to get all "data" table rows that id is related to "fields" table where in "value" column are phrases "foo" and "bar". Both for one or more "type" values. So I need to merge "value" column from all "type" rows and then search for phrases. My query below searches for both phrases in one row then concat the rows but I want the opposite. First merge then search.

```
SELECT `data`.*, GROUP_CONCAT(`f`.`value`) AS 'value' FROM `data` 
LEFT JOIN `fields` AS `f` ON `f`.`data_id` = `data`.`id` AND `f`.`type` IN ('1','2','3') 
WHERE `value` LIKE '%foo%' AND `value` LIKE '%bar%' 
ORDER BY `name` ASC LIMIT 20;
```

Above query returns only 1 row with id "2" because of "foobarstring" in "fields" table, id 4

| id | name | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | two | foobarstring |

Correct query should return 2 rows because both required phrases can be found for data_id 1 and 2.

Thanks

Comment: Explain what "doesn't work" actually means. Desired output will help.

Comment: Sorry, I just added it to the question

Comment: The condition by right table must be a part of ON clause condition, not in WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final result is this and it's works like a charm:

```
SELECT data.*, f.val FROM data
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT data_id, GROUP_CONCAT(value) val 
   FROM fields WHERE type IN ('1','2','3') 
   GROUP BY data_id
) f ON f.data_id = data.id 
WHERE val LIKE '%foo%' AND val LIKE '%bar%' 
ORDER BY name ASC LIMIT 20;
```

Answer (score 0):

From your comment to questions, I think what you are trying to do is get a list of all data where the given IDs contain any value that contains BOTH "Foo" and "Bar", even if they are individual records, OR both FooBar in a single string.

Since using a GROUP_CONCAT(), you need a "group by" clause for each individual data ID, otherwise it will nag at you about NOT having one, AND you have to include all non-aggregate columns in the group by.

As for the JOINING.  Since you know you are looking for BOTH possible strings, I am joining to the fields table with alias "f" looking for "foo" as you had, but then joining AGAIN on the fields table alias "b" for the "bar" consideration, but also that the f.value < b.value so when strings are returned it does not return one row as "foo, bar", and another as "bar, foo", but this one is a LEFT-JOIN, thus not REQUIRING the secondary join.

In the WHERE clause, I am testing for the conditions that either the f.value has both foo and bar as in your id = 2 string, OR... the first contains foo and second alias contains bar, thus two different rows on the same ID.

Finally, for your columns, since it is possible to get a one and/or the other columns, I have done a group_concat of both "foo" and "bar" values respectively.

```
SELECT 
      d.id,
      d.name, 
      GROUP_CONCAT( f.value ) fValues,
      GROUP_CONCAT( b.value ) bValues
   FROM 
      data d
         JOIN fields f
            ON d.id = f.data_id 
           AND f.type IN (1, 2, 3)
           AND f.value LIKE '%foo%'
            LEFT JOIN fields b
               ON f.id = b.data_id
              AND b.type IN (1, 2, 3)
              AND b.value LIKE '%bar%'
              AND f.value < b.value
   where
       (    f.value LIKE '%foo%'
        AND b.value LIKE '%bar%' )
      OR (   b.value IS NULL
         AND f.value LIKE '%foo%' 
         AND f.value LIKE '%bar%' )
   group by
      d.id,
      d.name
   ORDER BY 
      d.name 
   LIMIT 
      20;
```

Comment: Still I got 1 row from your query but I found solution. Your advice about "GROUP BY" helps me a lot. Thanks.

Comment: glad you got something, bur revised query to do B.Value IS NULL since left-join to not REQUIRE the b condition.